# CRTP : returning a reference to the derived class?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, crtp

By what have I to replace the missing line to have this CRTP solution working ?

```
template<class Crtp> class Base
{
    public:
        inline Crtp& operator=(const Base<Crtp>& rhs)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < const_size; ++i) {
                _data[i] = rhs._data[i];
            }
            return /* SOMETHING HERE BUT WHAT ? */
        }

    protected:
        static const unsigned int const_size = 10;
        double _data[const_size];
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
};
```

Other question : does the solution you will provide has a cost at running time (compared to the solution where the operator is directly implemented in the derived class) ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Simply `static_cast` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return static_cast<Crtp&>(*this);
```

This has no cost at run time (but you might want to protect the constructor of `Base`).

Comment: Is there a difference with "*static_cast<Crtp*>(this)" ? (I have'nt tried) ? + Does the fact that Base have a public constructor can change the fact that the solution has no cost at run time (or is just to be sure that Base will be used as an abstract class) ?

Comment: @Vincent, little if any difference, at least in practice. To the second question: the latter.

Comment: @Vincent, because you're returning a reference and not a pointer your cast needs to be to a reference. And the constructor has nothing to do with it, since a reference doesn't create a new object.

Comment: @Mark : There was a star beforce the static_cast :  *static_cast<Crtp*>(this)

Comment: @Vincent, sorry I missed it - it blended in with the quote. Yes it will be identical.